# How to configure AWS-SDK to run locally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services

I've installed the aws-sdk to use files that I've got hosted on S3.  The docs and tutorials for this are pretty barebones so I'm not sure I've set it up right.  They actually don't say where to put the commands/code that they instruct you to use.  Here's what I've done:

- `gem install aws-sdk`
- Created `myapp/config/aws.yml` and added the following code:

  development (tried with and without quotes):
      access_key_id: 'someid'
      secret_access_key: 'somekey'
- When I try to run `rails s` I get:

  `/home/joe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/to_ruby.rb:196:in merge!': can't convert nil into Hash (TypeError)`

  then further in the stack trace I get:

  `from /home/joe/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@heroku/gems/aws-sdk-1.10.0/lib/aws/rails.rb:108:in load_yaml_config`

I figure I've got some bad config going on somewhere.  Has anyone encountered this problem?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Config file has to have capitalized name.  Has to be AWS.yml, not aws.yml.

Comment: I'm not sure that's really the cause. Maybe you stopped and started your rails server and it started working?